# How to link to specific page on website with custom tab

Tags: wordpress, facebook-timeline

Now that the App Profile Page is no longer available, I tried using this link provided by Facebook to open a specific file on a WordPress website to the custom tab:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

This worked well for `yoururl.com/` (main directory) which is also the `index.php` home page of the website. However, when I attempted to use a custom tab to connect to a different page on the site, such as `yoururl.com/about/` I received the dreaded 191 error message:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

The workaround I ended up using was to copy the source code of the page by hand and create a new standalone HTML document, but I would really rather have the custom tab open the actual page so my client can update the WordPress herself without me having to edit the HTML for small changes.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Facebook app settings may not be correct. Your site url should be the url to your main website domain homepage, eg http://www.domain.com Then your canvas url should be a link to the page you are trying to pull in, eg http://www.domain.com/facebook-tab
It *should* be as simple as that....*fingers crossed*

Comment: Thank you Lucy. I tried that and got an error message that didn't describe the error: "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Comment: Here is an alternative answer - maybe Facebook is working on the replacement but it isn't done yet. After all, "recommendations" were deleted from business pages when the timeline was introduced and they just reappeared three or so weeks later. I'll be patient, but if anyone has an answer before that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a developer, but have been reading about building a custom app for my business page. I read that the url needs to be from a secure page url (https). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes, the site is hosted on a secure SSL. There is still a problem with displaying an individual page or even adding it to a canvas page successfully. Thanks.